# бинарных данных Это как?

Tags: php

бинарных данных Это как?

Строка практически любой длины. В отличие от C, строки могут содержать в себе так-
же и нулевые символы, что никак не повлияет на программу. Иными словами, строки
можно использовать для хранения бинарных данных.

Answer (score 1):

В си строки заканчиваются нулевым '\0' символом (и многие функции для работы с строками как раз это используют strlen и т.д.) потому говорится что "что никак не повлияет на программу".

А про бинарные данные как раз и имеется ввиду что пользователь в php может не заботится о нулевых байтах в строках (как это сделано в си) и использует строку как просто кусок памяти включая нулевые байты.

Что такое бинарные данные - это последовательность байтов которые в свою очередь состоят из последовательности битов (отсюда и название бинарные, так как используется двоичная система счисления)